# How to calculate sample and population variances in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have a vector `a`

```
a = [86 100 41 93 75 61 76 92 88 97]
```

And I want to calculate the `std` and `mean` by 
myself:

```
>> mean(a)

ans =

   80.9000

>> std(a)^2

ans =

  335.2111
```

But when I do it like that I get wrong variance:

```
>> avg = mean(a)

avg =

   80.9000

>> var = sum(a.^2)/length(a) - avg^2

var =

  301.6900
```

What do I miss here ?

why `sum(a.^2)/length(a) - avg^2 != std(a)^2` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var = sum(a.^2)/(length(a)-1) - (length(a))*mean(a)^2/(length(a)-1)


var =

  335.2111
```

`var` is computed as (unbiased) sample, not population variance.

For a complete explanation you can read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Population_variance).

From the matlab documentation,

> VAR normalizes Y by N-1, where N is the sample size.  This is an
>   unbiased estimator of the variance of the population from which X is
>   drawn, as long as X consists of independent, identically distributed
>   samples.

**but**

> Y = VAR(X,1) normalizes by N and produces the second moment of the
>   sample about its mean.  VAR(X,0) is the same as VAR(X).

so that

```
>> var(a,1)

ans =

  301.6900
```

Answer (score 2):

An unbiased sample variance is given by:

```
>> 1/(length(a)-1) * sum((a-mean(a)).^2)

ans =

  335.2111
```

[image]